# Can't JOIN tables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I need to get products based on chosen subcategory. Now, it displays all products. How to do this? Here is my code. How to pass Subcategory.Id in button click?

```
...
<td>Subcategory</td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2"
         runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
         SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [SubCategory] WHERE ([IdCategory] = @IdCategory)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="IdCategory" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</td>
</tr>
...



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT productName, quantity, price FROM Product JOIN SubCategory ON Product.id_subcategory = SubCategory.id", _connection);
...

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna assume that the `DropDownList2` control already contains the subcategory data.

You can get your subcategory ID in Button1_Click event with

```
DropDownList2.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Thats it. But can't understand, why each product displays 11 times, instead of 1. var query = "SELECT productName, quantity, price FROM Product JOIN SubCategory ON Product.id_subcategory =" +
                    DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                { result += "Name = " + Convert.ToString(reader["productName"]) + "; ";
                    }
                ReadAllOutput.Text = result }

Comment: Have you tested that sql query directly in the sql server management studio?
This might have something to do with your data or table structure, which resulted in unwanted duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following database table structure:

```
Product
- Id (PK)
- ProductName
- Quantity
- Price
- MainCatID (FK)
- SubCatID (FK)
- others...

Category
- Id (PK)
- Name

SubCategory
- Id (PK)
- Name
- IdCategory (FK)
```

1. Make sure to add the namespace `System.Configuration` so that you can access your connection string from your web.config file.
2. Instantiate an SqlConnection class to identify the database connection:
3. Create methods to display the list of categories and sub categories from their respective drop down list controls
4. Include an `AutoPostBack` property to DropDownList1 then set to true so that each time you select an item from the list, it will 'regenerate' a list of sub categories based from the selected category value.
5. Create an OnSelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList1 calling the DisplaySubCategories() method.
6. Create a method that will display list of products based from selected category and sub category values
7. Include similar process from Step #4 to DropDownList2
8. Call the two methods inside the page load event.

---

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DisplayCategories();
        DisplaySubCategories();
    }
}

void DisplayCategories()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Category";
    SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = data;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

void DisplaySubCategories(string ID)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Name FROM SubCategory WHERE IdCategory = @IdCategory";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCategory", ID);
    SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList2.DataSource = data;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Name";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Id";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplaySubCategories(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayProducts(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
}

void DisplayProducts(string mainCatID, string subCatID)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT productName, quantity, price FROM Product 
        WHERE MainCatID = @MainCatID AND SubCatID=@SubCatID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainCatID", mainCatID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCatID", subCatID);
    SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (data.Read())
    { 
        result += "Name = " + Convert.ToString(reader["productName"]) + "; ";
        result += "Quantity = " + Convert.ToString(reader["quantity"]) + "; ";
        result += "Price = " + Convert.ToString(reader["price"]);
        result += "<br />";
    }
    ReadAllOutput.Text = result;
    con.Close();
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

I removed all the existing SqlDataSource controls because I find them messy.

Update:

You can also declare the method DisplayProducts() inside the Button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayProducts(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
}
```

PS: Some syntax might be incorrect (case-sensitivity) and I'm not using an IDE as of the moment.